# How do I map a message from USBSniffer to PyUSB?

Tags: usb, pyusb

I'm trying to figure out how to turn "TrueColor" on for a Microsoft LifeCam. I have a couple big USB logs from USBSniffer, and some sequences which consistently show up when I click the checkbox in Microsoft's software. Here's a request from the beginning of the enable sequence, and the device response (please correct me if I'm misinterpreting this data btw):

```
[156918643 ms] UsbSnoop - FilterDispatchAny(ac56afd2) : IRP_MJ_INTERNAL_DEVICE_CONTROL
[156918643 ms] UsbSnoop - FdoHookDispatchInternalIoctl(ac56b1ea) : fdo=88b25448, Irp=889911d8, IRQL=0
[156918643 ms]  >>>  URB 1482 going down  >>> 
-- URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE:
  TransferFlags          = 00000001 (USBD_TRANSFER_DIRECTION_IN, ~USBD_SHORT_TRANSFER_OK)
  TransferBufferLength = 00000002
  TransferBuffer       = abb04b86
  TransferBufferMDL    = 00000000
  UrbLink                 = 00000000
  RequestTypeReservedBits = 00000000
  Request                 = 00000085
  Value                   = 00001600
  Index                   = 00000500
[156918644 ms] UsbSnoop - MyInternalIOCTLCompletion(ac56b126) : fido=00000000, Irp=889911d8, Context=894d6c98, IRQL=2
[156918644 ms]  <<<  URB 1482 coming back  <<< 
-- URB_FUNCTION_CONTROL_TRANSFER:
  PipeHandle           = 885639a0
  TransferFlags        = 0000000b (USBD_TRANSFER_DIRECTION_IN, USBD_SHORT_TRANSFER_OK)
  TransferBufferLength = 00000002
  TransferBuffer       = abb04b86
  TransferBufferMDL    = 8837fee0
    00000000: 40 00
  UrbLink              = 00000000
  SetupPacket          =
    00000000: a1 85 00 16 00 05 02 00
```

Now, I'd like to send the sequence of requests I've seen via PyUSB, but when I send that first one, I get:

```
>>> ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0x80, 0x85, 0x1600, 0x0500, 8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
  File "c:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\usb\core.py", line 702, in ctrl_transfer
    self.__get_timeout(timeout)
  File "c:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 539, in ctrl_transfer
    timeout
  File "c:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\usb\backend\libusb0.py", line 387, in _check
    raise USBError(errmsg, ret)
usb.core.USBError: (None, 'usb_control_msg: invalid request 0x85')
```

For what it's worth, a simple GET_STATUS seems to work:

```
>>> ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0x80, 0, 0, 0, 8)
>>> print ret
array('B', [0, 0])
```

Why would a request which gets answered in one case be invalid in another? Syntax? Device state?

Answer (score 2):

From the very helpful [USB Made Simple](http://www.usbmadesimple.co.uk/ums_4.htm), the request type's highest 3 bits are formatted like so:

```
D7 Data direction
0 - Host-to-device
1 - Device-to-host
D6:5 Type
0 = Standard
1 = Class
2 = Vendor
3 = Reserved
```

The log says I'm using USB's Class interface (cf. "URB_FUNCTION_CLASS_INTERFACE"), so the RequestType is specific to the device class (audio, physical... in this case video). The GET_STATUS command works because it is of the Standard type.

So a more correct command is

```
ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0xa0, 0x85, 0x1600, 0x0500, 8)
```

I say *more* correct because the command returns data, but it's still not the data I expect!

EDIT: for complete verisimilitude, I needed to specify the recipient as the interface, according to the rest of the request type table from USB Made Simple:

```
D4:0 Recipient
0 = Device
1 = Interface
2 = Endpoint
3 = Other
4-31 = Reserved
```

...and also set the length to be the same as the sniffed request, so the true version of the command is:

```
ret = dev.ctrl_transfer(0xa1, 0x85, 0x1600, 0x0500, 2)
```